# How to use php5-cgi with nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I just installed php5-cgi on my Ubuntu 12.04. I am not sure about:

1. What configuration I will need to do in nginx config file to use it.
2. How will I start the service, as sudo service php5-cgi says "unrecognized service"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `php5-cgi` doesn't include a service that can be started.

From the package description:

> This package provides the /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 CGI interpreter built
>   for use in Apache 2 with mod_actions, or any other CGI httpd that
>   supports a similar mechanism.  Note that MOST Apache users probably
>   want the libapache2-mod-php5 package.

Therefore you need an installed web server like Apache.

To enable `php5-cgi` create a symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/php5-cgi.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled
```

and change the configuration via

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/php5-cgi.conf
```

An other option to enable an apache2 module is `a2enmod`. Therefore you could also use

```
sudo a2enmod php5-cgi
```

After that don't forget to restart the apache2 service

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

as commented by [@ThomasW.](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-w)

> for `nginx` you should be using `php5-fpm`, NOT `php5-cgi`

Comment: Also note that for `nginx` you should be using `php5-fpm` which is what the nginx people recommend, and NOT `php5-cgi`.

Comment: I was earlier thinking that nginx will fall under "or any other CGI httpd that supports a similar mechanism", but I guess not. php-fpm worked for ngingx. Thank you!! :D